# Google App Engine Overriding Default Reminders in Google Calendar API V3

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-calendar-api

I have written a Google App Engine program that inserts events into a calendar using Google Calendar API V3. The program can override default reminder settings. Although the program inserts the event without problems (no status 4xx), the newly inserted event still uses the default settings. Suggestions would be appreciated!

Here are some details:

1) In the API console, I register a service application and download the private key.

2) I converted the PK12 key to a PEM

```
openssl pkcs8 -nocrypt -in privatekey.pem -passin pass:notasecret -topk8
```

-out pk.pem

3) In the calendar settings, I share the calendar with the service application via its xxx@developer.gserviceacount.com.

4) In the calendar settings, I give the program the ability to change events.

5) I use SignedJwtAssertionCredentials for authentication

```
f = file("pk.pem", "rb")
key = f.read()
f.close()
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
                   service_account_name='xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
                   private_key=key,
                   scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar')
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = build('calendar', 'v3',http=http)
```

6) I specify the calendar by its calendarId.

```
 service.events().insert(calendarId='@group.calendar.google.com',body=event).execute()
```

In turn, the event is:

```
event = { 'summary': 'Appointment from Google App Engine',
          'location': 'Somewhere',
          'start': {
                    'dateTime': start_time
                   },
          'end': {
                     'dateTime': end_time
                   },
          "reminders":
                   {
                      "useDefault": "False",
                      "overrides": [
                                      {
                                        "method": "email",
                                        "minutes": reminder_period
                                      },
                                    ]
                   },
          "description": description
          }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding sub = "email@example.com" to your SignedJWTAssertionCredential ?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reminders for the programatically inserted event were coming from my default calendar, not the calendar the event was being added to. I filtered out my default calendar from the view to workaround the issue. I could not find any other way (ie reminder useDefault False, "False", override, etc)